Wrapping a TCP socket with ROS2 or DDS
We have a sensor driver that communicates its data over TCP sockets (2).
We would like to read those data when both sockets are ready to read in order to synchronized data and put a timestamp on the synchronization.
We would like to write a library that will allow us to build either a publisher or a ros2 control hardware interface.
We are looking for a way to integrate the driver into ROS2, and we are wondering if there is a standard way/tool to wrap a TCP socket with DDS or ROS2 and implement standard actions like barrier synchronization, socket disconnection handling, fault handling, etc.

Afaik there is no best-practics for TCP with ros2_control.
But there exist some ROS implementations as you might have found already (ROS 1) https://github.com/pcdangio/ros-driver_tcpip
